# Solve fourth degree inequality $x^4 - (1 + (m + 1)^2)x^2 + (m + 1)^2 \geq 0$ where $m \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

Solve fourth degree inequality $x^4 - (1 + (m + 1)^2)x^2 + (m + 1)^2 \geq 0$ where $m \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried using substitution as follows:
$$ a = x^2 $$
$$ b = (m + 1)^2$$
Using the substitution:
$$ a^2 - (1 + b)a + b \geq 0$$
Substituting in the second degree equation:
$$ \frac{-(1 + b) + \sqrt{4 + (1 + b)^2}}{2} $$
Solving the binomial coefficients $(m + 1)^4$ and $(m + 1)^2$, I got:
$$ \frac{-(1 + (m + 1)^2) + \sqrt{m^4 + 4m^3 + 8m^2 + 8m + 8}}{2} $$

From here I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: you get positive and negative solutions, so that the inequality is true, when x is less than the negative root and greater than the positive root. since large values of x yield x^4 being really large.

Comment: Do you want for what value of $m$, does the inequality hold true for all $x \in \mathbb R$.  Or, do you want given a value of $m \in \mathbb R$, what are solutions for $x \in \mathbb R$ for which the inequality holds true?  As of now, it is difficult to decide which interpretation follows from "Solve the inequality..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake. From here
$$ a^2 - (1 + b)a + b \geq 0$$
you went here
$$ a=\frac{-(1 + b) + \sqrt{4 + (1 + b)^2}}{2} $$
While the correct solution is
$$a=\frac{-(1 + b) + \sqrt{ (1 + b)^2-4b}}{2} =\frac{-(1 + b) + \sqrt{ (1 - b)^2}}{2}$$
$$a_1=1;\;a_2=b$$

$$a\le 1\lor a\ge b$$
that is
$$x^2\le 1 \lor x^2\ge (m+1)^2$$
or
$$-1\le x \le 1 \lor  x\ge| m+1|$$

Answer (score 1):

Your method might work, but I couldn't really see how to proceed. A substitution that I am sure would work is as follows:

First expand your polynomial: $x^4-(m^2+2m+2)x^2+m^2+2m+1$.

Next, you can use your $a=x^2$ substitution: $a^2-(m^2+2m+2)a+m^2+2m+1$. Then, you use essentially the same $b$ substitution, but expanded: $b=m^2+2m+1$. Once you do this you get $a^2-(b+1)a+b$, you solve and get $a=1, a=b$ (verify yourself that they work). Then substitute back $a$ and $b$: $x^2=1, x^2=m^2+2m+1$, so your solutions for $x$ are: $x=1$, $x=-1$, $x=m+1$, $x=-m-1$. Therefore, since an extremely large or small value of $x$ will make the equation positive, your range of x-values are $(-\infty, -|m|]\cap[-1, 1]\cap[|m|, \infty)$. Note when $m=-2$, your range of x-values are $(-\infty, \infty)$

**Edit:** My steps are essentially your steps (expanded out), but I didn't use quadratic formula like on the fourth step, but factored it.

Using what you have:

$ a = x^2 $

$ b = (m + 1)^2$

$ a^2 - (1 + b)a + b \geq 0$

$a=b, a=1$ are solutions to the inequality, and solve for bounds

The rest is the same.

Comment: Expansion isn't really needed, its $(x^2-1)(x^2-(m+1)^2) \geqslant 0 \iff (x-1)(x+1)(x-m-1)(x+m+1)\geqslant 0$.  Also the solution intervals (including how many) depend on value of $m$.  Further in the case $|m|>1$ your expression for the solution set will hold true, but with union of intervals, not intersection.

Comment: @Macavity I had edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done in high school, using Vieta's relations and results on the sign of a quadratic polynomial:

First set $y=x^2$ and solve for $y$: you have the quadratic inequation
$$y^2-\bigl(1+(m+1)^2\bigr)y+(m+1)^2 \ge0,\qquad y\ge 0.$$
The discriminant is
$$\Delta=\bigl(1+(m+1)^2\bigr)^2-4(m+1)^2=\bigl(1-(m+1)^2\bigr)^2,$$
therefore the quadratic polynomial in $y$ has two roots $y_0$ and $y_1\;(y_0\le y_1)$.

Furthermore these roots are nonnegative, since $y_0+y_1=\bigl(1+(m+1)^2\bigr)^2>0\:$ and $\:y_0y_1=(+1)^2\ge 0$.

Conclusion; the original inequation is equivalent  to

$$0\le y\le y_0\;\text{ or }\;y\ge y_1\iff \begin{cases}-\sqrt{y_0\mathstrut}\le x\le \sqrt{y_0\mathstrut},\\
\quad\text{ or }\\ x\le -\sqrt{y_1\mathstrut},\enspace x\ge\sqrt{y_1\mathstrut}. \end{cases}$$